# attr() doesn't change an id - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change id of div after every click on it. But the .attr() change it only once, after first click.

```
$(function(){
  $('#m1').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#m1').attr("id","m11");
    $('#m11').after('<div id="info_cont1">Hello m11 </div>');
  });

  $('#m11').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#m11').attr("id","m1");
    $('#m1').after('<div id="info_cont1">Hello m1 </div>');
  });

});
```

Any ideas of such behaviour?

Comment: better to bind click on class instead of id because id would change once click on it.

Comment: Use class for selectors.

Comment: Your scripts runs once document is ready, it finds all elements with id `m1` and add event listeners to them, then make the same with elements with id `m11`, but when you load page, your element has only one of these 2 id's, this is why your code work only once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are binding the second .click function to the element #m11 which does not exist at that point, but the code runs at that early point. Therefore, use delegation:

```
$(document).on('click', '#m11', function(event) {
    // code
});
```

SO the full code would be:

```
$(function(){
    // you could actually also use .on() here :)
    $(document).on('click', '#m1', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#m1').attr("id","m11");
        $('#m11').after('<div id="info_cont1">Hello m11 </div>');
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#m11', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#m11').attr("id","m1");
        $('#m1').after('<div id="info_cont1">Hello m1 </div>');
    });

});
```

Comment: You would need to use a delegate on the first click handler also, otherwise it will remain when only the second click handler should be trigggered.

Comment: This works fine. But I make it (a bit) complicated and again doesn't work. I actually want to make an event for input checkbox tag. I've modify the code but still it seems somewere is a problem. Does form elements are processed differently by .attr(). In the second comment I will place the code.

Comment: the code: $(function(){
 
 $( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click", '#in1', function(){
   //$(document).on('click', '#in1', function(e) {
        $('#in').attr("id","in11");
       $('#in11').after('<div id="info_cont1">Hello in11 </div>');
   });

   $( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click", '#in11', function() {
  // $(document).on('click', '#in11', function(e) {
       $('#in11').attr("id","in1");
       $('#in1').after('<div id="info_cont1">Hello in1 </div>');
   });  

});

Comment: dude update question or make a new one but nobody wants to decode code from a comment :D

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `click` method, it is being used at the very beginning of your scripts execution, when `m11` doesn't exist.

If you simply want to toggle between id's `m1` and `m11` then do this:

```
$(function(){
  $('#m1').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).attr('id') == 'm1'){
      $(this).attr("id","m11").after('<div id="info_cont1">Hello m11 </div>');
    }else{
      $(this).attr("id","m1").after('<div id="info_cont1">Hello m1 </div>');
    }
  });
});
```